# IoT device recognition on connection. Blob storage sends a configuration file as a response

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

I have a doubt about how to do this.
I have various iot devices that send telemetry data using different variables, as each customer personalizes his own devices. Each device communicates with the iot hub and sends messages via endpoint to various different azure services which are then processed for statistical purposes. my goal would be that every time a new device connects to the network it is provided with a file (CSV or other type) for that device, containing all the variables to be used for that particular customer. How could I make it happen?
thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you had a look on Device Twins https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins

Comment: do you mean that in the function, between blob storage and the device, I insert a SAS token of the file that I want to be downloaded into the metadata of the twin device?

Comment: Thinking if the Twin can be set during Device registration or by some other UI\Service and when the Device connects it directly reads its Device Twins setting to identify what is needed or identify which setting is needed.